# At what levels do you unlock game modes?

Tags: dota-2

In DOTA2 you no longer start with all the game modes unlocked. Is there a chart somewhere that indicates at which levels you unlock *Ability Draft*, *All Random*, *Random Draft*, etc? I've googled around and can't find a specific answer for any of those modes, much less a comprehensive table or list. (I'm assuming the unlocks are based on the meta-game levels, but I guess it could be games played, total wins or some other criterion.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- Level 1: All Pick
- Level 4: Random Draft
- Level 5: Ability Draft
- Level 6: Single Draft
- Level 7: Least Played
- Level 10: Captain's Mode/Captain's Draft
- Level 13: Ranked Matchmaking

Taken from the table [here.](http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Profile_Level) Things like wins, games played, etc. don't factor in, so if you really want to jump through the levels, you can always grab a battle booster to get through them more quickly.

Comment: Do you know when All Random is unlocked?

Comment: Good question, it seems a riddle. Some say lvl 13, some are lvl 20+ and still cannot select it. I knew a while back a couple of modes where locked due to maintenaince or bugs.

Comment: I am level 12 and can play AR, so I'm not sure that's the case.  Pretty sure I've been able to play it since level 10 (this is all after the update which made these level locked).  Also doesn't a battle booster just increase BP by 80%? All levels require 1000 BP, so I don't think you can "rocket through 2-3" in one game, but it certainly does make it go faster.

Comment: 1 - 6 are less than 1000 BP (level 2 takes 120, for instance) and if you grab one of the 500% boosts off the market you can pull 300+ BP per game. I've edited my answer accordingly, though.

Comment: @Majuju Ah I think you're right, I played through the single digits, then stopped for a while and forgot how quickly the lower levels go. I think only 80% boosters exist at the current moment though.

Comment: For what it's worth, my friend ended up unlocking All Random at level 9.